# Java + MongoDB: unnesessary connections

Tags: java, mongodb, database-connection

Created a singleton class to maintain MongoDB, but it still creates a new connection each time it's initialised.

```
public class MongoDB {

private static MongoDB ourInstance = null;
private DB db;
private MongoClient mongoClient;


public MongoDB() throws UnknownHostException {
    try{
        // To directly connect to a single MongoDB server (note that this will not auto-discover the primary even
        // if it's a member of a replica set:
        mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
        db = mongoClient.getDB( "roam" );
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e){
        System.out.println("Could not establish database connection");
    }
}

public DBCursor setCursor (String collectionName, BasicDBObject query, BasicDBObject field){
    return db.getCollection(collectionName).find(query, field);
}



public static synchronized MongoDB getInstance() {
    if (ourInstance == null) {
        try {ourInstance = new MongoDB();}
        catch (Exception e) {throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);}
    }
    return ourInstance;
}

protected void finalize (){
   this.mongoClient.close();
}
```

}

As I create a web app, it creates a new connection each time a page with DB reference is refreshed.

Comment: Are you trying to maintain the singleton instance of `MongoDb` class?

Comment: I'm new into Java, so maybe I do something wrong, but I've tried to create a singleton MongoDB class, yes...

Comment: In a singleton pattern, the constructor of the class must be `private`.. so that no outside class will be able to instantiate the class. Can you try making constructor `private MongoDB() ` ?

Comment: Oh(( that's bad, 'couse I have to call DB from another classes, and there is no way to do it with private constructor.

Comment: Then I am afraid, it violates the singleton pattern. With singleton pattern, `getInstance()` should only be the way, an outer class can get hold of your singleton instance. Please check [this][http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern]. As far as multiple connections getting created is concerned, I think, calls from another classes causing them.